# Form button submit no redirect

Tags: php, forms, animation, svg

Let's start with the code

PHP

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['EMAIL'];
$message = $_POST['Message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$to = 'email@example.com';
$message = 'FROM: '.$name.' Email: '.$email.'Message: '.$message;
$headers = 'From: EMAIL' . "\r\n";

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { // this line checks that we have a valid email address
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //This method sends the mail.
echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message
}else{
echo "Invalid Email, please provide an correct email.";
}

?>
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
    <meta name="description" content="Responsive Bootstrap Landing Page Template">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Bootstrap, Landing page, Template, Registration, Landing">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="author" content="Nick McNil">
        <title></title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <!-- Include roboto.css to use the Roboto web font, material.css to include the theme and ripples.css to style the ripple effect -->
    <link href="css/material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/ripples.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-invers menu-wrap">
      <div class="navbar-header text-center">
        <a class="navbar-brand logo-right" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="img/neslogo1.png" alt=""></i></a>
      </div>
        <ul id="navbar" class="nav navbar-nav main-navigation">
          <ul id="navbar" class="nav navbar-nav main-navigation">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html"> </a></li>
          <li><a href="#why"> </a></li>
          <li><a href="past.html"> </a></li>
          <li><a href="ceu.html"> </a></li>
          <li><a href="arc.html"> </a></li>
          <li><a href="current.html"> </a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact"> </a></li>
        </ul>
        <button class="close-button" id="close-button">Close Menu</button>
    </div>

    <div class="content-wrap">
     <header class="hero-area" id="home">

      <div class="container">
          <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse sticky-navigation navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <a class="logo-left " href="index.html"> </a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-right">
                  <button class="menu-icon"  id="open-button">
                    <i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i>
                  </button>             
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
       <section id="contact">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
            <h2 class="section-title">Contact Us</h2>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="info">
                  <div class="icon">
                    <i class="mdi-maps-map"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h4>Locations</h4>
                  <p> </p>
                  <p> </p>
                  <p> </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="info">
                  <div class="icon">
                    <i class="mdi-content-mail"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h4>Email</h4>
                  <p> </p>
                  <p> </p>
                  <p> </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="info">
                  <div class="icon">
                    <i class="mdi-action-settings-phone"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h4></h4>
                  <p></p>
                  <p></p>
                  <h4></h4>
                  <p></p>
                  <h4></h4>
                  <p></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>        
          <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
            <h2 class="section-title">Love to Hear From You</h2>
            <!-- Form -->
            <form class="contact-form"  method="post">
              <i class="mdi-action-account-box"></i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name">

              <i class="mdi-content-mail"></i>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Email">                  

              <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" rows="4"></textarea>  
            </form>

              <!-- progress button -->
<div id="progress-button" class="progress-button">
    <!-- button with text -->
    <button><span>Submit</span></button>

    <!-- svg circle for progress indication -->
    <svg class="progress-circle" width="70" height="70">
        <path d="m35,2.5c17.955803,0 32.5,14.544199 32.5,32.5c0,17.955803 -14.544197,32.5 -32.5,32.5c-17.955803,0 -32.5,-14.544197 -32.5,-32.5c0,-17.955801 14.544197,-32.5 32.5,-32.5z"/>
    </svg>

    <!-- checkmark to show on success -->
    <svg class="checkmark" width="70" height="70">
        <path d="m31.5,46.5l15.3,-23.2"/>
        <path d="m31.5,46.5l-8.5,-7.1"/>
    </svg>

    <!-- cross to show on error -->
    <svg class="cross" width="70" height="70">
        <path d="m35,35l-9.3,-9.3"/>
        <path d="m35,35l9.3,9.3"/>
        <path d="m35,35l-9.3,9.3"/>
        <path d="m35,35l9.3,-9.3"/>
    </svg>

</div>
<!-- /progress-button -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section> 

    <section id="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
        <div id="footerimg" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
            <img src="nesfoot.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <h3>Navigation</h3>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="ceu.html">Ceu Courses</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="arc.html">Arc Flash Services</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="current.html">Current Projects</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <h3>About</h3>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Team</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="current.html">Current Projets</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>  
      </div>      
      <!-- Go to Top Link -->
      <a href="#home" class="btn btn-primary back-to-top">
      <i class=" mdi-hardware-keyboard-arrow-up"></i>
      </a>
    </section> 

    <section id="copyright">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p class="copyright-text">
             Copyright Here
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>     
    </div>  


    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ripples.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wow.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/count-to.js"></script>   
    <script src="js/jquery.inview.min.js"></script>     
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.nav.js"></script>      
    <script src="js/smooth-on-scroll.js"></script>
    <script src="js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
    <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="js/uiProgressButton.js"></script>




    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // This command is used to initialize some elements and make them work properly
            $.material.init();
        });
    </script>
<script>
            [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.progress-button' ) ).forEach( function( bttn, pos ) {
                new UIProgressButton( bttn, {
                    callback : function( instance ) {
                        var progress = 0,
                            interval = setInterval( function() {
                                progress = Math.min( progress + Math.random() * 0.1, 1 );
                                instance.setProgress( progress );

                                if( progress === 1 ) {
                                    instance.stop( pos === 1 || pos === 3 ? -1 : 1 );
                                    clearInterval( interval );
                                }
                            }, 150 );
                    }
                } );
            } );
        </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

So I recently created a contact us form for a client and had the entire form submitting via php to an email. The client then decided he wanted an animated button to confirm or reject the submission. I have been able to get the button to continue to submit the php email. My issue is he doesn't want the page to redirect (currently it calls send.php) to the php page but rather just validate and confirm sent by the animated button. Any insight would be appreciated.

EDITED**

So I have taken a look at the many suggested changes and still can't seem to get this figured out. Here is the button the client is wanting to use on the site http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircularProgressButton/. I have followed the edits as suggested by everyone thus far and when I incorporate the edits my button quit workings. I am unable to place it in the `<form></form>` tags because it will not call the script and run. It seems to me that the changes cause the page to refresh. I have modified the provided HTML to include the entire page html. I know it's not clean; I still have some tidy up to do.

so to recap
client wants the animated button (svg animation) to confirm (green check mark) or deny (red X) form submission.
No redirect to send.php file (but still have php send email to him).

Nick

Comment: you can use Ajax for this

Comment: i dont have alot of experience with ajax any examples or reading you would recommend

Comment: Is it possible for you to combine the html page with the form and the php file?  If that is possible, you can change the form `action` attribute to the page itself and put all your php in an if statement: `if(!empty($_POST)) { // make email }`.  Then change the button also based on if the POST (or GET) data is there or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree this is best achieved with AJAX.  You don't need much to do a simple post:

**Add to your HTML file:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // listen for the form submission
    $('#form1').submit(function(event) {
        // disallow browser form submissions
        event.preventDefault();
        // once submitted, put the form data into a serialized string
        var formData = $('#form1').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "php/send.php", // <-- your existing PHP file
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                // this is where you can initialize your animated button and feedback
                $('#someElement').html(data);  // <-- Your echoed PHP messages will be returned here
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This example uses jQuery since it is the simplest implementation. You'll need to add a link to the library somewhere if not already used in your project.

**Your PHP File**

Once you have set this up in your HTML file you can simply adjust the corresponding PHP file to accept the POST data.  This should work with the serialized data as such:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // set your variables from the post values
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["EMAIL"];
    $message = $_POST["Message"];

    // the rest of your php script goes here

}
```

Additionally, your submit button is not inside the form tags and does not correctly reference the form.  You will need to move inside the form or add some additional script to make it functional i.e.

```
// inside the form
<button type="submit">Submit</button>

// outside the form
<button type="submit" id="sendMessage">Submit</button> 

$("#sendMessage").click( function() {
    $('#form1').submit();
});
```

**Some other notes and recommendations**

- Sanitize your user input properly
- Validate form input with JS/Jquery on the client side and/or PHP

Comment: thank you for your help, I have adjusted my inital post to included my entire HTML. I tried making your changes but they don't seem to work. The pages refreshes and doesn't animate the button as well as not properly call the php file to send. Maybe i am miss understand what i need to do. Any ideas?

Comment: There are still issues with the HTML you have edited above.  The submit button needs to be inside the form or referenced in your javascript before it can be submitted.  The message field in your form is missing the name property.  Additionally, I do not see the AJAX call in your HTML, did you add that to the same file or was it added to one of your external JS files?

Comment: I ended up reverting the HTML back to where i started because the button animation wasn't working. If i place the button in the <form> tags it fails to animate but outside the <form> tags it will animate. Also if i place the script in place because it is outside of the tags it doesn't animate simply refreshes the page

Comment: i just took alook at the page in chrome under the developer tools and it seems with the script placed to allow the button to be outside of the <form> tags it is actually processing the animation just not showing it. But when i load it to the server to test the ajax/php it looks like it will run the animation for about 1 millisecond then refreshes the page and doesn't go through

Comment: The SVGs to animate are contained within the "progress-button" div and therefore must be moved with the button still inside those tags.  If you look at the JS and CSS files supporting the animation they look for the element with a "progress-button" class.  It should animate if you move the entire div with the button and SVGs in between the form tags.

Comment: It appears the "main.js" file in your project has an issue and is preventing the script from running.  You may be able to circumvent it by replacing the `$(document).ready(function(){` line with this `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {`

Comment: Thank you for your help! i can't believe i didn't catch the main.js issue. I have corrected it and volia it works!. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem.  Glad to hear to you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('#_btn').click(function() {   
    $('#_err').html(&&);    
        var e = $("#e").val;    
        var p = $("#p").val;    
        if(e == null || e == ''){   
            $('#_err').html('Email Required');  
        } else if(p == null || p == ''){    
            $('#_err').html('Password Required');   
        } else {    
            $.ajax({    
                type: "post",   
                url: "proccess.php",    
                data: $("#_form").serialize(),  
                success: function(response){    
                    if(response == 'Success'){  
                        $('#_err').html('Complete, Thank you!');        
                    } else {    
                        $('#_err').html('Error: '+response);    
                    }   
            }); 
        }   
}); 
});
</script>

HTML
<form id="_form">
    <input id="e" name="e" value="" placeholder="Email">
    <input id="p" name="p" value="" placeholder="Password">
</form>
<button id="_btn">Send</button>
<div id="_err"></div>
<?php
$to = 'email@example.com';
$message = 'FROM: '.$name.' Email: '.$email.'Message: '.$message;
$headers = 'From: EMAIL' . "\r\n";
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);){
        echo "Success"; // success message
    } else {echo 'Connection Error';}
}else{
    echo "Invalid Email, please provide an correct email.";
}
?>
```

i added to check if mail was actually sent.  You should always check this as well.  also i added example to make sure field is not empty. this will save server resources. (you should check on the server as well, there is ways to edit on the client side.)